# whether a particular SharePoint list item or library item has more than one users as the permission granted users

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

In C# how do I know whether a given particular SharePoint list item or library item has more than one users as the permission granted users? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you want to get the number of users in a group named "users"?

Comment: no no i want to know whether a given item can be accessed by one user or more than one user.

Answer (score 0):

i found a WSS 3.0 web service that contains the Permissions class and it contains below shown method

```
public XmlNode GetPermissionCollection (
    string objectName,
    string objectType
)
```

by using this method permission granted users can be returned as a XML fragment, but as far as i know this works only for Sites and Lists, but not for the List Item.